# Sql query to csv stream

Tags: mysql, node.js, stream, nestjs, export-to-csv

I am trying to convert my sql query to csv and send it as a stream file to the client but id doesn't work.

Here is my code

```
  @Get('csv')
  public async exportCases(
    @Query('params') params: string,
    @Request() req: AuthenticatedRequest,
    @Res() res: Response,
    @I18n() i18n: I18nContext
  ) {
    const result = await this.caseService.streamAllByCompanyId(
      req.user.currentCompanyId as string,
      decodeTableParams(params)
    );
    let prependHeader = true;
    res.header('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
    res.attachment('cases.csv');

    const transform = new stream.Transform({
      objectMode: true,
      encoding: 'utf-8',
    });
    transform._transform = async (chunk, _, done): Promise<void> => {
      const casesWithJe: CreateCaseCsvDto[] = this.convertStreamToCaseCsvDto(
        [chunk],
        i18n
      );
      const convertedToCsv = await new Promise((resolve) =>
        resolve(this.convertCasesToCsv(casesWithJe, i18n, prependHeader))
      );
      prependHeader = false;
      done(null, convertedToCsv);
    };
    const writeFile = fs.createWriteStream('cases.csv');

    // const readFile = fs.createReadStream('cases.csv');

    result.pipe(transform).pipe(writeFile);
}
```

The conversion to csv is working as expected, but nothing is sent to the front-end.

like the file is not being sent to the client.

I tried to convert mysql query to csv file and send it to client using node stream

Comment: it's nestjs and not javascript

Comment: Give us an overview of the data flow (not just the code).  Where does the data originate?  Where does it need to end up (apparently "in a MySQL table").  Why is JS/nestjs/whatever involved?